# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I have to show the following is equivalent to the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:

$$\left( \sum (r_i +s_i )^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}} \leq \left( \sum r_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}  + \left( \sum s_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}$$

The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is defined as :
$$ \left( \sum {(r_i s_i)} \right)^2 \leq  \left( \sum{r_i}^2 \right)\left( \sum{s_i}^2 \right) $$

**My Attempt:**

Since both sides are non-negative we can square both sides.

$$ \sum (r_i +s_i )^2 \leq \sum {r_i ^2}  +2 \left( \sum r_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}\left( \sum s_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}} +  \sum s_i ^2  $$

Expanding the left-hand side.

$$ \sum (r_i^2 + 2r_is_i + s_i^2 )\leq \sum {r_i ^2}  +2 \left( \sum r_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}\left( \sum s_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}} +  \sum s_i ^2  $$

Using identities of Summation.

$$ \sum r_i^2 + 2\sum {(r_i s_i)} + \sum s_i^2 \leq \sum {r_i ^2}  +2 \left( \sum r_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}\left( \sum s_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}} +  \sum s_i ^2  $$

Cancelling like terms 
$$
 \require{cancel}
\cancel  {\sum r_i^2} + 2\sum {(r_i s_i)} + \cancel{\sum s_i^2} \leq \cancel{\sum {r_i ^2}}  +2 \left( \sum r_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}\left( \sum s_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}} +  \cancel{\sum s_i ^2}  
$$

We obtain the following:

$$ 2\sum {(r_i s_i)}  \leq  2 \left( \sum r_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}\left( \sum s_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}
$$

Dividing by 2:
$$ \sum {(r_i s_i)}  \leq   \left( \sum r_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}\left( \sum s_i ^2 \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}
$$

It is at this point that I am stuck. Does squaring both sides preserve the inequality at this point?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should write what you call Cauchy Schwarz inequality to.

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is $\left(  \sum (r_i s_i) \right)^2  \leq \left( \sum r_i^2 \right) \left( \sum s_i^2 \right)$

Comment: @Joanpemo Fixed

Comment: But then you already have it! Just square both sides in your last line and it is exactly what you cal CS inequality. And yes: squaring preseves the inequality. The other way around can be false, though.

Comment: If that is negative then the inequality is trivially true, and otherwise you can square. The other way around is not generally true, as  $\;a^2=b^2\implies a=\pm b\;$ , so equality or inequality cannot be assured.

Comment: Just check it: $\;2^2=4=(-2)^2\;$ , yet $\;2\neq-2\;$, or $\;(-3)^2>2^2\;$ , but $\;(-3)\rlap{\;\,/}>2\;$

Comment: @Joanpemo I think you misunderstood.  I was referring  to "If that is negative then the inequality is trivially true" . If $\sum{r_i s_i}$ <0 then how is $ \left(  \sum (r_i s_i) \right)^2  \leq \left( \sum r_i^2 \right) \left( \sum s_i^2 \right)$?

Answer (score 1):

> Does squaring both sides preserve the inequality at this point?

In a word, "yes":
$$
\sum(r_{i} s_{i})
  \leq \left|\sum(r_{i} s_{i})\right|
  \leq \left(\sum r_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum s_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2},
$$
with the second inequality being the square root of "your" Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

---

As a stylistic point, two-column proofs are a (less-than-optimal) habit from school courses that should generally be outgrown if you aspire to be a mathematician. In published work, mathematicians instead build *chains of equalities and inequalities*. Here, for example, you might argue that "your" C-S inequality implies the "new" one like this:
\begin{align*}
\sum (r_{i} + s_{i})^{2}
  &= \sum r_{i}^{2} + 2 \sum (r_{i}s_{i}) + \sum s_{i}^{2} \\
  &\leq \sum r_{i}^{2} + 2 \left|\sum (r_{i}s_{i})\right| + \sum s_{i}^{2} \\
  &\leq \sum r_{i}^{2} + 2 \left(\sum r_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum s_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2} + \sum s_{i}^{2} \\
  &= \left[\left(\sum r_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2} + \left(\sum s_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\right]^{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: By "two-column proof" I mean an argument that starts from one (in)equality and proceeds (as in your question) by performing operations to both sides, arriving at a conclusion. (Or worse, that starts with the desired conclusion and arrives at a tautology. Many "proofs" that $0 = 1$ have this form.) In published papers and most textbooks, you'll find (in)equalities are proven by starting on one side and building a succession of equalities (or "$\leq$"s) leading to the other side. [...]

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize your existing argument, incidentally, but _am_ pointing out that (i) chains of (in)equalities are generally preferable, and (ii) in this case can be made fairly short (e.g., four steps). :)

Comment: I don't mind criticism. I would love to "hear" how one prove that two inequality without the use of the "two-column proof". Would it be simply dealing with the LHS and RHS one at a time?

Comment: The four-step inequality in my answer is (omitting square roots) a proof of one direction. :)